# How to use Ajax "like" button on Django posts list

Tags: django, ajax, button

I created my first site with Django and I'm trying to make the Ajax "like" button work on the listing posts page, but I have to reload the page to have +1.

My views:

```
def likes_post(request):
    post_id = None

    if request.method == 'GET':
        post_id = request.GET['post_id']

    like = 0

    if post_id:
        post = Post.objects.get(id = int(post_id))
        if post:
            like = post.likes + 1
            post.likes = like
            post.save()
        return HttpResponse(like)
```

My HTML template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
 <div class="post-favourite">

<a href="#" data-posts-id="{{post.id}}" class="like text-danger">J'aime <i class="fa fa-heart-o likes_count"aria-hidden="true"> {{ post.likes }}</i></a>

</div>

{% endfor %}
```

and the Ajax function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.like').click(function(){
    var ps_id;
    ps_id = $(this).attr("data-posts-id");
    $.get('/likes_post/', {post_id: ps_id}, function(data){
        $(this).prev().find('.like_count').html(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

The Ajax button for the `post` detail page works  by simply replacing the last line with

```
$('.like_count').html(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

in your **views.py**, you should send back data to jquery with JsonResponse

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def likes_post(request):
   post_id = None
   if request.method == 'GET':
        post_id = request.GET['post_id']

    like = 0

    if post_id:
        post = Post.objects.get(id = int(post_id))
        if post:
            like = post.likes + 1
            post.likes = like
            post.save()
        return JsonResponse({'like':like})
```

and then in your jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.like').click(function(){
    var ps_id;
    ps_id = $(this).attr("data-posts-id");

$.ajax({
        url: '/likes_post/',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
            'post_id': ps_id,
        },
        success: function(data){
            $(this).prev().find('.like_count').html(data);
            $(this).html(data);
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

whatever you send with **JsonResponse** is accessible in **success** part of jquery. in this example the **like** we send is **data** in **success** part. 
in success part you can write **data** in your html code

Comment: thanks for your answer @Amir big ! when i run your code i have this TypeError in the terminal :  TypeError: In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False. So i add : return JsonResponse(like, safe=False) but i also have to reload the page to have the +1 like

Comment: oh... i'm sorry, my mistake. i updated my answer. check **JsonResponse**. see if this works

Comment: i'm not a javascript developer, but i'm sure problem is in **success** part. because we can modify django model and we are receiving data from django view. i wrote two sentence in success part, check which one works.

Comment: thank you very much for your time I tried the 2 sentence but it doesn't work :(